# Scala list index

Tags: scala, collections

Can someone please explain why an explicit call to `apply()` is needed after `map()`

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l(2)
res56: Int = 3

scala> l.map(x => x*2)
res57: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)

scala> l.map(x => x*2)(2)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[Int],Int,?]
              l.map(x => x*2)(2)
                              ^

scala> l.map(x => x*2).apply(2)
res59: Int = 6
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `map` method takes a second, `implicit` argument list with a `CanBuildFrom` implicit parameter:

```
def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

Scala compiler interprets your code as if you're trying to pass `2` where the implicit `CanBuildFrom` is required.

The usage of `CanBuildFrom` and ugly method signatures that come with it is a very controversial element of Scala collections library that is regularly discussed and criticized.

Another issue here is the fact that Scala allows explicit passing of implicit parameters. I would personally argue that it shouldn't be allowed and then we could avoid many issues similar to yours. But that is of course a matter of opinion.